# bootstrap 3 dynamic modal - ajax content caching issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need a dynamic bootstrap modal, depending on the id I sent to an exterior page in the same domain the result needs to come to me in a bootstrap modal. The system works when you first load the page but if I click on another link to open different modal I should see different result but it only shows the first result...which is basically caching the result.

Here is what I have done. I also tried sending timestamp etc but it is still the same.

```
<a href='modal_window.php?mpage_id=$mpage_id' mpage_id='$mpage_id' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'> open modal </a>
```

This is my modal on the same page

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-  labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

So how can I load remote content without caching the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following JavaScript to purge the cache every time the modal is displayed:

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
});
```

It's also worth noting that [remote modals are being deprecated](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/14034) in Bootstrap v3.2.1 and will be removed entirely in Bootstrap v4.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the dynamic link to the modal, but before that clear the previous modal link every time when the modal is loaded with new link

Comment: can you please give an example of how to do it please?

Comment: @T.c.YusufTokgoz something like: modal_window.php?mpage_id=$mpage_id&_=123342412323 You can use random function to generate unique hash.

Comment: hi littlealien, i have tried that but it still didnt stop it caching. clearing the content was the best one.thank you anyway