# How to load remote content for modal dialogs?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to use modals to show some small forms retrieved via AJAX or similar.

I have found some similar question and answers already here, but a comment about [deprecation of remote for modals](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/14034) too ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25318493/390177)).

To be compatible with the future version 4 of bootstrap, I want to implement it on the "right" way, but I don't have any clue how to do it.
Most stuff I found is for 3.1 or earlier.

I would register an event listener on **show.bs.modal** and load the content, but is it the "right" way?

Thanks for any hints how to start.

Comment: `$("#myModal").html(htmlresponse)` ??

Comment: WOW! Fast response, where can I find more information about it?

Comment: You retrieve the html code for the form via ajax...then you fill your modal div with that code and the display it...i have some code like this somewhere...searching...

Comment: Be sure to handle the error if the AJAX request fails.

Comment: There's no reason to wait until the modal is shown, why not get the form directly after the page has loaded? Use JQuery's ready() function. There pro's and con's to both ways of working, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from my generic modal:

```
<div class="modal fade in" id="generic-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySuccessModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div id="generic-modal-background" class="modal-content" style="background-color:#5cb85c; color:#fff;">
            <div class="model-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <div id="generic-modal-left">
                            <span id="generic-modal-icon" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-9">
                        <div id="generic-modal-right">
                            <p id="generic-modal-title" class="lead">Success!</p>
                            <p id="generic-modal-content">You did it, the changes were made!</p>
                            <button id="generic-modal-button" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Great</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have set ID's on the elements I wish to change, then when i call the model via jquery I update these id's with this function:

```
function showModal(modalType, title, content, button) {

        switch (modalType) {
            case "success":
                $('#generic-modal-background').css('background-color', '#5cb85c');
                $('#generic-modal-icon').removeClass();
                $("#generic-modal-icon").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-ok");
                break;
            case "fail":
                $('#generic-modal-background').css('background-color', '#d9534f');
                $('#generic-modal-icon').removeClass();
                $("#generic-modal-icon").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-remove");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        $('#generic-modal-title').html(title);
        $('#generic-modal-content').html(content);
        $('#generic-modal-button').html(button);

        $('#generic-modal').modal('show');
    }
```

And then I call the function show modal when I want to use it:

```
showModal("fail", "Error!", "There was an error saving your changes. Please try again later.", "Close");
```